# Сайт двигается в сторону

Tags: css, html5

Только начал делать сайт и столкнулся вот с такой проблемой. Без малейшего понятия, что делать. Даже не знаю как сформулировать вопрос правильней.[image: на картинке сайт сдвинулся направо]

Comment: а можно скрин поменьше? там всё равно ничего важного в 70%

Comment: В первую очередь сформулируйте [mcve]

Comment: приложите ваш код

Answer (score 0):

у какого-то элемента слишком большая ширина и он двигается в сторону.
если не можете увидеть это из вашего кода, нужно отладить в браузере.
вызовите веб-инспектор браузера и добавьте для отладки стиль * {box-shadow: 0 0 10px red inset} - тогда все элементы получат внутреннюю тень, которая не повлияет на их габариты, и вы увидите, из-за кого все расперло.